# Invoke device lock programmatically in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone application where I would like to automatically trigger the device lock. I also want to add an option to change the device lock pin code from my application. Is this possible?

Comment: Hum, "I'm smelling a keylogger". Pretty sure you can't. The app is very sandboxed. You almost can't run under lock screen.

Comment: Requirement for me is to integrate the device pin lock as a security feature for our application and it seems we have hit a road block :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the things you want is possible with the current SDK.